# Asp.Net: Slow Performance on IE

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We are developing an web application and hosted for public use. we have a dashboard page which shows some grids, filters and search options. Everything is working fine. But we have the following issue on Dashboard page: It takes 1 to 2 mins to load when we use the filter or search option in IE(Target Browser is > IE 8). The same filter and search option works very fast in Chrome or FF(5 to 15 secs) than IE.

Any one suggest me what could be the Issue???

Comment: You will need to give some more context - is it the client-side rendering that's slow, or the server-side? Have you used a profiler? Have you tried all versions of IE and what was the effect? Have you created a minimal implementation that reproduces the problem? Unfortunately, there is not enough information in your post to assist you as-is, but the above questions might guide you in resolving your issue.

Comment: Hi., I have checked all IE browsers. I think its very slow on client side as checked the processing time is very low (less than 2 sec) using logs.

Comment: Do you make heavy use of JavaScript? Chrome and FF have significantly faster JavaScript engines than older versions of IE (although I would be surprised if IE10 or 11 is that much slower as they benchmark similarly to Chrome and FF- can you confirm you've tested IE 10 and 11?)

Comment: I have tested up to IE 10 as we don't have IE 11

Comment: Then I would suggest you use the inbuilt [F12 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507.aspx) to profile your page and find out why it's slow.

Comment: Since I have used the developer tool, I found the following: In Network tab, the POST method taken 111 sec to load JS Library. what could be the reason???

Comment: I don't know! There is not nearly enough information here to help you. You don't even state what JS Library you are using. Please can you *edit your question* to include *all* relevant information - at the moment it basically reads "Something is taking a long time to load - why?" which is impossible to answer...